# Proving an ideal prime with algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals

An exercise in Fulton's book  *Algebraic curves* (2.8) asks to prove that the algebraic set in ${\mathbb C}^3$ defined by the ideal $I=(xz -y^2,yz-x^3,x^2y-z^2)$ (meaning $V=\{P\in {\mathbb C}^3: F(P) \mbox{ for all } F\in I\}$) is irreducible. I did that by first defining $J$ to be the radical ideal of $I$, that is $J=\{F\in {\mathbb C}[x,y,z]: F^n \in I \mbox{ for some } n\}$, so that $V$ is also defined by $J$,  and then defining the polynomial map $\varphi: {\mathbb C} \longrightarrow {\mathbb C}^3$, $\varphi(a) =(a^3,a^4,a^5)$ onto $V$, from which it follows that the induced map on coordinate rings $\hat{\varphi}: \Gamma(V)={\mathbb C}[x,y,z]/J \longrightarrow \Gamma({\mathbb C}) \eqsim {\mathbb C}[x]$, $\hat{\varphi}(F)(x) = F(x^3,x^4,x^5)$ is one-to-one, and so $\Gamma(V)$ is isomorphic to a subring of ${\mathbb C}[x]$, that is a domain, from which it follows that the ideal corresponding to $V$ (which by the Hilbert Nullstellensatz is $J$) is prime, and therefore $V$ is irreducible.

But suppose I also want to prove that the ideal $I$ is prime. It seems to me that the above argument is useless because an algebraic sets does not see the difference between an ideal and its radical. Is there some other argument involving algebraic geometry to prove that $I$ is prime?

Comment: Well, $I=J$ here, so once you show that you're all set. In general, if the underlying topological space of $V(I)$ is irreducible, this means that $\sqrt{I}$ is prime, so if you want to show that $I$ is prime you'd better show that $I=\sqrt{I}$. Still, knowing that $\sqrt{I}$ is prime is a big step, so these sorts of arguments are very useful.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks...How could one see that $I=\sqrt{I}$ in this particular example?

Comment: Hint: if $I\neq \sqrt{I}$, then there's some poynomial which vanishes on points of the form $(t^3,t^4,t^5)$ which isn't in $I$. Show that this cannot happen.

Comment: @KReiser Here is a proof I came up with, but I wonder if there is a better way: if I divide $F(x,y,z)$ by $y^2-xz$, then by $x^3-yz$, then by $z^2-x^2y$, I get a remainder $R$ that has degree at most 2 in $x$ and at most 1 in $y$ and $z$, and if $a_{ijk}$ is the coefficient of $x^iy^jz^k$ in $R$, it turns out that by evaluating $R$ at $(t^3,t^4,t^5)$ all powers of $t$ are distinct, and so it can be $0$ for all $t$ only if all coefficients $a_{ijk}$ are $0$, and so $F$ is in $I$.  But this  only works because $3i+4j+5k$ are all distinct for $i\leq 2$, $j,k\leq 1$.